# Unable to conceal text in a region

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have this:

`syntax match Text /Completed/ conceal`

It conceals any text matching `Completed`.

However, if `Completed` is in a region, I am unable to conceal the match. For example, if I place a `#` sign in the line that `Completed` is on, the word `Completed` is always shown because the `#` sign creates a region from that line.

I was unable to find anything in the documentation that addresses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Needed the `containedin` property:

`syntax match Text /Completed/ conceal containedin=NAME_OF_CONTAINING_REGION`

Comment: `Completed` again can be a keyword :)